# How to reset password using Django and gmail

Tags: django, gmail

I am trying to make user allows to reset their forgotten password
I got this error

> (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError 77sm14812049pfx.85 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')

I have some following codes.# settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

and urls.py

```
path('password-reset', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='register/passwords/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'),
path('password-reset/done', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='register/passwords/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='register/passwords/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('password-reset-reset', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='register/passwords/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

Comment: Please turn on ```Allow less secure apps``` in gmail.
https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that your environment variables are working. Do they display the expected values? Try printing them to the terminal to check.

Second, make sure you register your app in your gmail account. [this](https://medium.com/@whizzoe/in-5-mins-set-up-google-login-to-sign-up-users-on-django-e71d5c38f5d5) link will be helpful. You can go try and test your code by changing the email setting in your settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "sent_mail")
```

This creates the email in a sent_mail folder in your base directory. If you receive the email there, your code works fine.

Good luck!

**EDIT

Just setup the email settings for a app i am creating and got the same error. Fixed it by registering the app in my Google account. You get a custom password for the specific app only. Copy this one into your email-password environment variable and it should be working perfectly fine!

https://myaccount.google.com/ --> security -> app passwords

*note: make sure to add 2 factor authentication.

Comment: Oh, it works after following your edited tutorials. Thanks